# Adding Chinese Input Loki

Tags: release-loki, input

I have followed the instructions on numerous other questions, but none of them work, how am I supposed to install pinyin (preferably google pinyin) on elementary os loki?

After installing fctix (and googlepinyin), enabling it in im-config, and restarting, I get this: (No input options nor a wing panel icon)[image]

I also tried running im-config as sudo (separate restart), and purging both im-config and fctix and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

[2 Best Chinese PinYin Input Method in Ubuntu 16.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/2-best-chinese-pinyin-im-ubuntu-16-04/)

1. If you installed the fcitx, run im-config in your terminal
2. Select "OK", on the dialog box that pops up.
3. When asked to update user preferences, select "Yes".
4. Select fcitx from the list, and select "OK".
5. Restart your computer, and you should see an icon for fcitx in
       the wingpanel.

   Ctrl+Space is used to switch between inputs.

[image]

Comment: I took the steps you suggested, see my updated post